# Can I change basic form input field to multi-line text input field using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to convert `<input placeholder="Form Input" />` to `<textarea>Form field for multiline text input</textarea>` using CSS. Basically I want to ask, can I `convert a single line form input to multiline form input without using <textarea> tag.` Is it possible or not?

Comment: what's the problem with  TextArea?

Comment: No. You can't do that. That can be achieved by `<textarea>` tag only.